# Parent killing n children using signals after parent creates them

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork

I am trying to create n child processes from a parent process, then after the n children are created, the parent must kill them one by one using signals.

When the parent kills a child, the parent must wait 2 seconds before killing the next one. Lastly, when the parent has killed all the children, the parent must finish as well.

Each child when created must print its process id until parent kills it. I tried to combine what I read from various websites, and so far I am able to create the children and print their process ids, but I am not able to kill them using signals. How do I do that?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handle_sigint(int sig) { 
    signal(sig,handle_sigint);
    exit(0);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *ptr=argv[1];
    int n=atoi(ptr);//number of processes to be created
    pid_t p[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
        signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);    
        if ((p[i] = fork()) == 0) {
            while(1) 
                printf("%d %d\n",getpid(),i);                   
        } 
        sleep(2);                                
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        kill(p[i],SIGINT);
        sleep(2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if( p[i]=fork() == 0)` => `if( (p[i]=fork()) == 0)`. `==` has higher precedence than `=` (assignment).

Comment: Your signature for the signal handler function is wrong, and you can't safely use `exit()` in a signal handler...

Comment: for some weird reason it worked, i added a few things, for ex, i put n=3, it first creates process 0, then 1 then 2 and then 0 dissapears then 1 then 2 and the program exits. Il update the code for you to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, you don't need a signal handler, because there are many signals whose default action is to cause the receiving process to terminate.  The `SIGINT` you're already using is one of those, in fact, but `SIGTERM` would be a more appropriate choice for the purpose.  I would simplify by getting rid of the handler and its registration, and I would have the parent send `SIGTERM` instead of `SIGINT`.

If you do retain the signal handler, though, then you should use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), not `signal()`, to register it, and you should omit the re-registration from the handler implementation, as proper use of `sigaction()` makes it unnecessary.  Also, signal handlers are permitted to call only [async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), and `exit()` is not one of those.  You could use `_exit()` or `_Exit()` instead, but again, it would be simpler to just drop the handler altogether.

All that notwithstanding, however, I'm inclined to suspect that the reason the original code failed was the incorrect signature of the signal handler, which you corrected in your edit.  It's still wrong for the handler to call `exit()`, but in practice, it is reasonably likely that the manifestation of the resulting undefined behavior includes the program terminating.

Comment: Okay, i changed and used SIGTERM and also removed the signal handler. But i get this error now, as i did before if i didnt use signal handler.error: ‘handle_sigterm’ undeclared

Comment: @ChristoforosProdromou, I can only suppose that instead of removing the call to `signal`, you changed the name of the handler function you are passing to it (to one that does not exist).  You do not need a handler for the signal to terminate the process that receives it, therefore, you do not need to call `signal`.  This is the main point, not the removal of the function itself, though the function should indeed be removed if you do not use it.  But if you *do* call `signal()` then you must pass it a signal handler that actually exists.